# Calculate distance between many points in cartesian plane and group it

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a Matrix of NxN, for example 10x10, I have many points or coordinates in my matrix like a Cartesian plane, for example:

```
(2,5)
(-5,8)
(3,6),
(9,2)
(-4,-4)
(8,-3)
(2,1)
```

I need create group of three coordinates, but with the closer coordinates in distance.

I need crete an algorithm to calculate and makes groups.

I was thinking of using the mathematical formula of distance between two points:

```
d=sqrt(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

But I need the distance of one point to other points, and if the matrix is bigger I have an optimization problem

for example the distance between (2,5) and (-5,8) is 7.6, (2,5) and (3,6) is 1.4, then like the distance between (2,5) and (3,6) is small is posible that these two coordinates are in the same group, The problem is that I need calculate the distance with each one

What is the best way to do it.

To Group the coordinates of Groups of 3 or X value.

Comment: *"with the closer coordinates in distance"* As far as you described it, that is an ill posed problem, you'd have to better formulate what you want/need. Consider solving by hand in a few examples then seeing how you create those groups. Also, Why do need optimization? I'm guessing you'll need to compute all distances regardless, and that can be parallelized.  But creating the groups is like an NP problem.

Comment: This sounds like a [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) problem, but without more details all I can suggest is reading through that Wikipedia page.